# Android Hyperlinks in Pop up

Tags: android, popup, android-alertdialog

I want a popup box to come up and I want the text in the box to hyperlink any valid links in the box. In my example, it is a email address. I am using an AlertDialog currently, is there someway to make the link clickable, or should I try something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of what you want to do, you might consider [Creating a Custom Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) with a `TextView` in it. You could then use the [android:autoLink](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#autoLink) attribute on the `TextView` in the layout xml.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that documentation and make that work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not seeing you code. is it a custom dialog ?? you can place button in AlerDialog

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(a).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setButton2("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          //place what you want to do here 
              return ;
    } });
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I was just looking for the action attached to the Button. It works as I wanted.